# Why is this page reloading instead of creating a popup?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a button that should open up a popup but instead reloads the page. I use link_to which works, but the button_to doesn't. Changing the button_to to a GET request doesn't work. How do I force it?

```
<%= button_to "Invite your friends", :id => "invite_fb_friends" %>
<div id="fb-root">
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){
      $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function(event) {
        FB.init({
        appId:'255295947482349',
        cookie:false,
        status:true
      });
        FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'This is a test message.'});
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
     });
  </script>
</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
#For the button

<form method="post" action="/profile?id=invite_fb_friends" class="button_to">
<div><input type="submit" value="Invite your friends" />
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="1bgr+0o9j/gs4sgD7hItkc3BFR1ewVh5VyXCZRoMrtY=" />
</div></form>

#For the link
<div id="friends">
<p><a href="#" id="invite_fb_friends">invite your friends</a></p>
```

Comment: Beware the code above - there's a return statement before the event.preventDefault()

Comment: Not anymore ;) although that didn't fix your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button_to generates a form with a submit button that posts the form.
Maybe you should try link_to or just regular markup:

```
<input type="button" value="Invite your friends" id="invite_fb_friends" />
```

Comment: I had a link_to but changed it to a button for user experience reasons. Surely there's a work-around?

Comment: @Simpleton you still expect it to be anchor in your selector $("a#invite_fb_friends")

Comment: You're right about the form. I've updated the code. Even if I remove the anchor so it's just $("#invite_fb_friends") it doesn't change anything.

Comment: just try the regular input markup I posted, I don't really see the point of generating it with rails.

Comment: I'll accept this and just use link_to image_tag & use CSS to make it look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prevent the click event from bubbling (and performing the default action, which in this case will be to navigate to the same page, with the :id param set to "invite_fb_friends").

in JQuery, that's event.preventDefault()

see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Doesn't work. I've updated the code in the question to reflect it.

Comment: You're returning from the method before calling preventDefault